# EF Core How to join with %

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

So I am trying to join 3 tables and one of the joins i need to match up sku's that have additional stuff on the end.
ex. 'WERTY123' to 'WERTY123blah'

this SQL query works in Microsoft SQL server.

```
SELECT b.ModifyDate, p.IsEmbroidery, p.IsEngraving, p.IsMetal, p.IsUv
FROM BarcodeScan b
INNER JOIN ShipStationAwaitingOrder s ON b.ShipStationOrderId = s.SSOrderId 
INNER JOIN Product p ON s.ItemSKU LIKE  p.Sku + '%'
WHERE b.ModifyDate LIKE '2022-06-07'+'%'
```

and this is my linq query.

```
var TodaysList = (
            from b in _context.BarcodeScan
            join so in _context.ShipStationAwaitingOrder
            on b.ShipStationOrderId equals so.SSOrderId
            join p in _context.Product
            on so.ItemSku equals p.Sku + '%' 
            where EF.Functions.Like(b.ModifyDate.Date.ToString(), nowTime.Date.ToString())
            select (new
            {
                ModifyDate = b.ModifyDate,
                SKU = so.ItemSku,
                IsEmbroidery = p.IsEmbroidery,
                IsEngraving = p.IsEngraving,
                IsMetal = p.IsMetal,
                IsUV = p.IsUv
            })
            ).ToList();
```

How can I do the 'equals' with p.Sku + '%' ?

Comment: to add onto this the sku with extra stuff will always be attached to the end

Comment: Check this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#collection-selector-references-outer-in-a-where-clause). How to do INNER JOIN without `join` operator.

Comment: have u tried to put bracket on p.Sku + %?  like this=>   so.ItemSku equals (p.Sku + '%' )